# using particles to create pumpkins how can i get them all to emmit the light from inside

Tags: particles

i created a pumpkin to use as body for particle system but i can’t get them all have light emitting faces can anyone tell me how to do this please iv tryed control + j but as the light is not mesh they will not join

Comment: are you using cycles, BI or EEVEE?

Comment: im using cycles... iv now figered out i can use a mesh cube to emmitt from and join the two meshes so now got light up faces but i want the light to emmitt out of the holes in the pumpkins more than it is doing

Comment: Can you post an image of your results?